# Autogenerate consecutive job numbers per group using QGIS expressions

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, qfield

I am looking to autogenerate consecutive numbers per group by an attribute form default expression whilst completing a survey using QField for QGIS.

**Requirements:**

- A job number will only be created when a separate column, "SpanClear" = No.
- I also require the job numbers to reset to 1 for each unique group in the column named "CircuitID".
- As this is a survey to be completed in QField, the attributes start off empty/null and will be populated on a mobile device
- Each time a job is identified (by "SpanClear" = 'No'), the jobs should be consecutively numbered, 1, 2, 3... etc.
- I require an expression to add in the default value of the attributes form (if there is a better way, please let me know)

I have searched through many previous questions and although there are workarounds using plugins, virtual layers and tools in QGIS, I require an expression so it will work in QField.

I want to automate the numbering to reduce chances of errors during surveying.

The expression I have created so far is:

```
CASE 
    WHEN "SpanClear" = 'No'
    AND 
    "JobNo" is NULL
    THEN $id=array_first(array_agg($id, "CircuitID"))
    
    WHEN "JobNo" is not NULL
    THEN  array_agg((maximum("JobNo")+1),"CircuitID")
    ELSE
    NULL
END
```

The above expression names the first job per group "1", but any following jobs are set to "0".

Is what I am asking for even possible through an expression? I'm not a developer so I may have missed something obvious.

**How it will look in QField**

[image: Table to autogenerate consecutive job numbers per group BY EXPRESSION for surveying in QField for QGIS]

**How the current expression is autopopulating**

[image: Table when autopopulated using current expression]

**How the expression looks in Attributes Form**

[image: Expression in dialog box]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what you meant to achieve with the `$id=array_first(array_agg($id, "CircuitID"))` part of your expression, as that's what is returning the `1` and `0` values.

It's checking whether the current feature's `$id` value matches the first `$id` value in the same `CircuitID` group (according to no particular order...). If it does - it returns a `1` (true), if not, a `0` (false). Only one feature can result in a match, hence why you start with one `1` and all the rest in that `CircuitID` group have a value of `0`.

I presume you meant to use that as a condition for another expression that would generate the incremental value, but because you preceded it with `THEN` - it's actually returning the check itself.

---

This default value expression in the `JobNo` widget will get you started:

```
CASE WHEN "SpanClear" = 'Yes' OR "SpanClear" IS NULL 

THEN NULL 

ELSE 

coalesce("JobNo",coalesce(maximum("JobNo","CircuitID"),0)+1)

END
```

The first 3 lines should be self-explanatory, but here is what is happening with line 4 working inside out:

1. `maximum()` function. You don't need to use the `array_agg()` function here as `maximum()` can already aggregate/group by within the function itself. This finds the maximum value for `JobNo` within the group that has the same `CircuitID` as your current feature.
2. The second `coalesce()` function. Checks if the result of step 1 is `NULL`, and if it is, returns `0` instead. This is for situations where there is no `maximum()` because you are entering a new `CircuitID` (so no existing features to group), or the existing `CircuitID` group has not been updated (so all `JobNo` values in that group are `NULL` and a maximum cannot be calculated).
3. `+1` - this increments the result of step 2 (which is either the maximum `JobNo` for your `CircuitID` group, so you go one up, or it's 0, so you start your sequence at 1).
4. The first `coalesce()` function. Checks if `JobNo` already has a value in it - if it does, then it leaves it alone. Otherwise, it applies the above sequence. This is so that if you check 'Apply default value on update' in the widget, and you go back to a feature that already has a `JobNo` applied (say job number 2 out of a current max of 4 in that `CircuitID` group), if you update a completely unrelated field like comments, it doesn't recalculate the `JobNo` (overwrite the existing value of 2 to 5, the new maximum + 1).

---

Make sure your form is properly designed so you make sure `CircuitID` and `SpanClear` cannot be null for a form to be saved.

---

You may need to tweak the expression depending on how you want your form to behave when you go back and edit records.

One option may be to disable 'Apply default value on update' so that once the `JobNo` is calculated the first time, it is locked in place.

But what if you initially said `SpanClear = No` for a record and now you want to revise that to `SpanClear = Yes` (or vice-versa?)

If it already had a `JobNo` do you want to retain it overwrite it with `NULL`? If the latter, do you want all the other `JobNo` values in that `CircuitID` group to readjust (in which case you'll need a virtual field)? or are you ok with there being a gap in the sequence? etc.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Thanks for taking the time to also explain how it works. I am just starting out in writing expressions so I was taking code from other answers but not understanding what the code was doing.

Comment: Regarding your questions on overwriting the job number, I think disabling the 'Apply default value on update' would be the best option. I know that jobs can be missed, however, and will be required to be added at a later time. This means job numbers are not always geographically linear.

Thank you for your help, I will test in the field and provide feedback.

Comment: No worries, it is always easier to help when the question has all the info needed in it including screenshots. When you test the expression out and you find this answer solves your question, don't forget to mark it as answered to help others down the track when they have the same issue!