# Adding automatic numbering of the "id" field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, unique-id, autoincrement

I'm working on QGIS 3.22.6 and I would like to find a way for my `"id"` column to be automatically numbered as geometry is added.

I am currently using `maximum("id") + 1` within the *'default value'* of the Attributes Form, but this isn't good enough as it requires me to manually number the `"id"` of the first feature to `1` in order for it to work.

Has anyone got a solution?

Comment: Geopackages have a native fid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first feature returns a `NULL` for `maximum("id")` as there are no `id` values to calculate a maximum on.

To get around this, use the [`coalesce()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#coalesce) function which returns the first non-null value in a series of parameters — `coalesce(expression1, expression2, expression3)` is a more concise version of `CASE WHEN (expression1) IS NULL THEN (expression2) CASE WHEN (expression2) IS NULL THEN (expression3) ....`

For the first feature to be 1, use `coalesce(maximum("id"), 0) + 1` as your default value.

Which means that when you digitise your first feature and `maximum("id")` returns `NULL`, you go to the next parameter in `coalesce()`, which is `0`. Then add `1` to that.

From your second feature onwards, `maximum("id")` returns the maximum `"id"` value (maximum `"id"` from existing features = `1`, `2`, `3`...)

And then adds `1` to that (result `"id"` for current feature = maximum `"id"`+ 1 = `2` (1+1), `3` (2+1), `4` (3+1)...)

See [Autogenerate consecutive job numbers per group using QGIS expressions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455396/autogenerate-consecutive-job-numbers-per-group-using-qgis-expressions?rq=1) and the comments to this answer to  [Is there a way of auto_increment for the ID column in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/312406/98784).